# Create a List of Employee having particular age and increase their salary using Streams in Java 8

Tags: java, list, java-stream

Below is the `Employee` class.

```
public static class Employee {
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int salary;
    
    // constructor, getters, setters, etc.
}
```

There is a list of employees.

And I need to get the list of employees whose `age` greater or equal to `32` years, then make their `salary` increased by `50%` and collect those employees in a new list.

*Sample data:*

```
List<Employee> el = new ArrayList<Employee>();

el.add(new Employee("A",30,3000));
el.add(new Employee("B",32,3000));
el.add(new Employee("C",33,5000));
```

*My attempt:*

```
el.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getAge() >= 32)
    .map(i -> i.getSalary() *3 / 2)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But this is returning a list of type integer - `List<Integer>`. Instead, I want the returned list to be a list of Employee type - `List<Employee>`.

Comment: Please share your attempt and describe the specific issue you've encountered. And also change the title to reflect this issue.

Comment: Help us help you - share some code. At the very least, we'd need to see your Employee class.

Comment: Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1):

It's not a good practice to change the state of elements in the stream.

Instead, you can filter employee having the target age with streams. And then apply salary change using method `Iterable.forEach()`.

```
List<Employee> employeeOlder32 = el.stream()
    .filter(i -> i.getAge() >= 32)
    .toList(); // for Java 16+ or collect(Collectors.toList()) for earlier versions
        
employeeOlder32.forEach(employee -> 
    employee.setSalary(employee.getSalary() * 3 / 2)
);
```

---

***Sidenote:*** a common practice is to use [`BigDecimal`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/math/BigDecimal.html) for prices, salary etc. (not `int` or `double`).

Comment: Why not alter member field on the objects as they are streamed?

Comment: @BasilBourque That's a good question. And there are many things to consider. Let's start from the basic notions: **1.** *Side-effect* - an action that cause a mutable instance of a class to be changed (it's not necessarily about collections). **2.** [*Pure function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function) - a function that has **no** side-effects including **mutation of arguments** **3.** We have [API requirements regarding stateful behavior and side-effects](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#Statelessness).

Comment: @BasilBourque Let's sum up: we are dialing with an *action* (there's no need to return anything), and it's a *side-effect*, therefore semantically it's a job for `forEach()` and `forEachOrdered()` which are meant to operate via *side-effects*, and we have **API requirements** regarding these operations. Documentation explicitly says that they should be used with caution and considered as a suitable tool when we have no other options.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<Employee> newEmployees = el.stream().filter(emp -> emp.getAge() >= 32).map(emp -> {
  emp.setSalary(emp.getSalary() * 3 / 2);
  return emp;
}).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You cant modify data in stream , eventually you need to create new list and store manipulated data in it .

```
List<Employee> newList = el.stream()
         .map(f -> new Employee(f.getName(),f.getAge(), f.setSalary((f.getSalary()*3)/2)))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

The other two Answers both say you should not or cannot alter the objects being streamed. That instruction is incorrect, as far as I know. I suspect they are confusing the rule that you **should not modify the *structure* of the collection** being streamed, such as adding/deleting objects to the source list. You can modify the *content* of the collection’s elements.

## Modify objects while streaming

As we stream the list, on each `Employee` object element we call the `Employee#setSalary` to update with a newly calculated value.

With expanded notation, the key bit of code follows.

As we stream the list, we use [`Stream#forEach`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#forEach(java.util.function.Consumer)) to run some code on each element.

Multiplying our `int` field `salary` by a `float` type results in a `float` value. Calling [`Math.round`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#round(float)) converts that back to an `int`.

```java
employees
        .stream()
        .forEach (
                ( Employee employee ) ->
                {
                    employee.setSalary ( 
                        Math.round( employee.getSalary () * 1.5F ) 
                    );
                }
        )
;
```

Here is the full example, using compact notation.

For convenience, we use `List.of` to produce an unmodifiable list in literals syntax.

```java
List < Employee > employees = List.of(
        new Employee( "Alice" , 30 , 3000 ) ,
        new Employee( "Bob" , 32 , 3000 ) ,
        new Employee( "Carol" , 33 , 5000 )
);
System.out.println( "Before: " + employees );

employees.stream().forEach( employee -> employee.setSalary( Math.round( employee.getSalary() * 1.5F ) ) );
System.out.println( "After: " + employees );
```

Results:

```
Before: [Employee[name=Alice, age=30, salary=3000], Employee[name=Bob, age=32, salary=3000], Employee[name=Carol, age=33, salary=5000]]
After: [Employee[name=Alice, age=30, salary=4500], Employee[name=Bob, age=32, salary=4500], Employee[name=Carol, age=33, salary=7500]]
```

---

Just FYI, here is the `Employee` class used above. Not interesting.

```
package work.basil.example.modstream;

import java.util.Objects;

public final class Employee
{
    // Member fields.
    private String name;
    private int age;
    private int salary;

    // Constructor
    public Employee ( String name , int age , int salary )
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    // Accessors
    public String getName ( ) { return name; }

    public void setName ( final String name ) { this.name = name; }

    public int getAge ( ) { return age; }

    public void setAge ( final int age ) { this.age = age; }

    public int getSalary ( ) { return salary; }

    public void setSalary ( final int salary ) { this.salary = salary; }

    // `Object` overrides.
    @Override
    public boolean equals ( Object obj )
    {
        if ( obj == this ) { return true; }
        if ( obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass() ) { return false; }
        var that = ( Employee ) obj;
        return Objects.equals( this.name , that.name ) &&
                this.age == that.age &&
                this.salary == that.salary;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode ( )
    {
        return Objects.hash( name , age , salary );
    }

    @Override
    public String toString ( )
    {
        return "Employee[" +
                "name=" + name + ", " +
                "age=" + age + ", " +
                "salary=" + salary + ']';
    }
}
```

Comment: Alexander's answer doesn't say it can't be done, just that it's a not a good practice, which I agree with. Streams are a functional idiom, and one pillar of functional programming is immutable data. Immutability isn't a hard requirement with Java streams but I do think it's good style.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Thanks for the comment. I do agree that wide-ranging or complicated alterations may not be appropriate for a stream. For a small-scale specific change like the salary modification shown here, I see no problem. I see `Stream#forEach` as being the new `for` loop.

Comment: `employees.stream().forEach()` does the same as `Iterable.forEach()`. The difference is that the latter doesn't require generating a stream to do the job, and there are **no** API requirements regarding `Iterable.forEach()` contrary to `Stream.forEach()`.

Answer (score 0):

Single line code:

```
List<Employee> empList = list.stream().filter(emp->emp.getAge()>32)
                .map(emp->{
                    
                    Integer increment = emp.getSalary()*2/100;
                    emp.setSalary(emp.getSalary()+increment);
                    return emp;
                    
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());
       System.out.println(empList);
```